# Check my Google App Indexing Android app in a Google Search

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-app-indexing

I am implementing Google App Indexing in my app. I have followed the tutorials and my app support this kind of deep links:

```
http://mywebsite.tk
```

And I have the required code so that it supports also:

```
android-app://com.my.package/http/mywebsite.tk/
```

I can open with my app any link with both structures, opening urls from an email, and even pasting the deeplink in Chrome directly. I have also passed the tests for Google App Indexing in Android Studio.

But what I want is the following button:

[image]

I have a custom parameter inside the url so that I can show different info. How can I make Google show that button? I don't have a website, only a domain to handle the deep link, but a website is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't 'make' Google show this button. All you can do is set out the bait (which you have done in spades, based on everything you've mentioned above — the only thing I can think of is that you didn't mention whether you've set up [Digital Asset Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app#connect-your-site-with-your-app) or not) and hope they eventually bite. It takes some time for them to find and then recognize the App->URL association you've set up.

Is your content currently showing in the results list at all, even *without* that button?

Comment: Thack you very much! The fact is that I don't have a website. I just use a TK domain to handle the deep links, but I read that a website is not neccessary.

Comment: Hmmm...do you remember where you read this? As far as I know, app-only content is still in an [invite-only beta](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/app-only)

Comment: From your Digital Asset Links link. You can manually opt-in. I did it some days ago with no answer :-(

Comment: Looks like the same link as my comment above so we are definitely thinking about the same thing. They're probably just swamped after the Firebase announcement two weeks ago. You could also try [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the team). We take care of handling all your links and routing, and all the links are automatically enabled for App Indexing.